# Parse non standard form to standard form in java

Tags: java, parsing

I want to write a Java parser that converts a non-standard form (NSF) Boolean function into a standard form (SF).

Example of a NSF:

```
A * B + D (A + B) C + A * B (A * B '+ A + B) D
```

To get a NSF to a SF, you must multiply out the brackets. SF from the above function is seen like this: `A*B + D*A*C + D*B*C + A*B*A*B'*D + A*B*A*D + A*B*B*D`

Does anyone have any idea how can I implement this?

thank you

Comment: If these are boolean variables then shouldn't A*B*B*D be simplified to A*B*D?
What have you tried? Do you have a parser to read in your current expressions, or are they coming in already parsed?

Comment: Obviously, you parse it, get a representation, transform that representation, and prettyprint the result. Anything more specific? What did you try? What did you already manage?

Comment: What simplifications should you be doing? Assuming * is your AND symbol and + is your OR symbol, note that A*B*(A*B+A+B) reduces to A*B.

Since both * and + are commutative, you may want to print your standard form in a canonical ordering.
Is B' a different variable than B?
Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: parse it into an expression tree (http://courseweb.sp.cs.cmu.edu/~cs200/lecture18/lecture18.html)

Comment: Thank you all for your participation. @Jim thats right A*B*B*D is simplified to A*B*D and I know, how to delete repetitive variable. My Problem is, I don't know, how to multiply out brackets.

Comment: @Jim: For Boolean logic, B' is often notation for *not* B.

Comment: @IraBaxter That is why I asked. Note that the two appearances of a quote symbol in the original post are quite different, one is B' the other is '+. I was hoping the original poster would clean up the typo either by removing the quote characters, or by making them appropriate. I will edit it and see if anyone approves my edit.

Comment: @Jim: I think the A*B '+ A  is sloppy typing; I think he meant  A* B' + A.  Most lexers I know for logic equations won't let you separate a trailing not sign from the identifier, but a leading not sign (sometimes written as "not" and sometimes as "-") will typically allow that.  Just a matter of personal taste and convention, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do 4 steps to achieve your purpose:

1) parse the expression using "standard" (unrelated to your terminology) parsing techniques and produce what amounts to a boolean expression tree representing the (parsed) expression.

2) apply boolean algebra rules to the expression tree, to convert it from the representation you don't want, to the one you do.  Your "standard form" appears to be conjunctive normal form (CNF), so you need distributive law algebra rules to "multiply out" products over sums (e.g.,  a*(b+c)), to "get rid of parentheses"

3) You then need to apply some simplification rules (e.g., subsumption, cancellation) to get rid of excess terms, e.g.,  a*b + a*b+c ==>  a*b  [a*b*c subsumed], and  a*b*a'+b*c ==>  b*c [a*..a' cancels out].  This is just more algebra rules.

4) PrettyPrint the resulting algebra term in a human readable format.

You can write all this by A) ad hoc hand coded recursive descent parsing and ad hoc rule application and prettyprinting, or B) you can get a parser generator (ANTLR is nice) to do the parsing, and do the rule manipulation by ad hoc methods, and prettyprint using some help like string templates, or C) you could get a tool that does parsing, builds trees, will apply algebra rules you define, and has prettyprinting built in.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) can do case C nicely.   You can see an [example of applying standard algebra rules that is a direct analog to your problem](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html?Home=DMSToolkit).

One of the issues that is really hard to get right is handling associativity and commutativity in the algebra, e.g.,   knowing that  A*B*A' is "false" is a consequence of the algebra rule  X*X'=> false, but you can't just check for the pattern in the algebra rule directly.  You have to apply the algebra rules accounting for commutivity. Same argument for associativity.   One of the things that DMS does nicely is handle that for you, if you declare the appropriate operators to have those properties.  You can see this in the example.

Alas, not coded in Java.