# Parsing and expanding algebraic equations that have variables using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, parsing

I am working on a VBA script that is parsing down a user input string for later evaluation. I have managed to get it down to the following, where the letters are variables that contain strings, numbers, or other functions to evaluate later. They are being compared in AND/OR statements that have yet unspecified variables, so I can't just evaluate it ahead of time. Thus, I have simplified this:

```
( ( [$$FIELD_1] [$$REL_GREATER_THAN] [$$FUNC_ROUND_OPEN] 6000.25 
[$$FUNC_ROUND_CLOSE] AND [$$FIELD_1] [$$REL_LESS_THAN] [$$FUNC_ABS_OPEN] 
[$$FUNC_FLOOR_OPEN] - 7000.99 [$$FUNC_FLOOR_CLOSE] [$$FUNC_ABS_CLOSE] OR 
[$$FIELD_1] [$$REL_LESS_THAN] [$$FIELD_3] ^ 2 + 8 ) AND ( [$$STRING_1] & 
[$$STRING_2] & [$$STRING_3] [$$REL_NOT_EQUAL] [$$FIELD_5] & [$$STRING_4] & 
[$$FIELD_4] ) ) OR [$$FIELD_6] [$$REL_EQUAL] [$$STRING_5]
```

by replacing the Booleans with variables, and I replaced AND with multiplication, OR with addition:

```
( ( A * B + C ) * ( D ) ) + E
```

What I need to do now is expand that out using the distributive property of algebra. The result would look something like

```
A*B*D + C*D + E
```

which I can then start substituting values back into.

The order the terms are in doesn't really matter, it just has to be grouped down into multiplication or addition. It has become a much harder problem than I initially thought, because I need it to be robust enough to handle other equations, not just this one particular example.

I have looked for something built into VBA that can do this naturally, but I haven't found anything yet. This is a similar question, but for Java and C: [Parse non standard form to standard form in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844023/parse-non-standard-form-to-standard-form-in-java/9867303#9867303). Unfortunately, the only answer there essentially boiled down to, "just parse it"... which is the part I need help with.

How can I programmatically figure out these distributive expansions? Is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: give an example of how you'd substitute values

Comment: That's kind of immaterial to the question. The variables represent Boolean relational expressions. I can't evaluate them before I finish parsing down into its most basic form, though. Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to programmatically do that expansion.

Comment: _” I can't evaluate them before I finish parsing down into its most basic form“_, if you show an example I could check for a very simple way to make it

Comment: @DisplayName Ok, I added in the immediate step prior. All of those relational comparisons got simplified down into the variables A, B, C, D, E.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a string with your equation

```
equation = "( ( 2 * 3 + 2.5 ) * ( -2.5 ) ) + 1.9"
```

you can `Evaluate` it

```
MsgBox equation & " = " & Evaluate(Replace(equation, ",", "."))
```

where the `Replace` is there to make sure you have the dot as decimal separator

here's a working snippet, where a I used a `Dictionary` to keep track of name variables and their value:

```
Dim equation As String
equation = "( ( A * B + C ) * ( D ) ) + E"

Dim varDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set varDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

With varDict
    .Add "A", 2#    ' assigning variable "A" the value 2.0
    .Add "B", 3     ' assigning variable "B" the value 3.0
    .Add "C", 2.5   ' assigning variable "C" the value 2.5
    .Add "D", -2.5  ' assigning variable "D" the value -2.5
    .Add "E", 1.9   ' assigning variable "E" the value 1.9
End With

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In varDict ' loop all variables
    equation = Replace(Replace(equation, key, varDict(key)), ",", ".") ' replace each variable name within 'equation' string with its corresponding value, and make sure you use dots for decimal separator
Next

MsgBox equation & " = " & Evaluate(equation) ' show the result
```

Comment: @SandPiper, any feedback?

Comment: @SandPiper, it'd be nice of you giving feedback to anyone trying helping you

Comment: Thanks @T.M. I wish I could get some feedback from SandPiper as well...

Comment: @Sandpiper - as I'm generally interested in parsing, I'd like to hear, too if the above approach meets your needs and/or where you can localize a special issue (if so please describe it :-)